# mapStateToProps with an ID?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Right now I have a generic function that gets all `Element`s

```
const mapStateToProps = ({elements}) => {
    return {
        elements: getElementsByKeyName(elements, 'visibleElements'),
    };
};
```

I'd like to change it to something along the lines of

```
const mapStateToProps = ({elements}) => {
    return {
        elements: getElementsById(elements, this.props.elementId),
    };
};
```

If I'm initializing my React class with a required `elementId` prop, is possible to achieve this rather than getting them all and filtering every time I need to be more specific in my view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `mapStateToProps` function takes the second argument which is own props(props passed to a component outside connect). You can grab the id that way if I correctly understood what you're trying to achieve.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({elements}, {id}) => {
  return {
    elements: getElementsById(elements, id),
  };
};
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Tomasz